# Program crashes when using scanf into third Array declared

Tags: c, arrays, crash

For some reason, I am able to use scanf for my char array, and the first numeric one, however, the program always crashes when I input the data for the next array, in this case, withdrawal[wt]. Please take a look at the code. I am taking an intro class to C, so I am obviously not an expert user.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    /* Declare Variables */
    float withdrawal[50] = {0}, deposit[50] = {0};
    char name[50];
    int number_of_deposits, number_of_withdrawals, x = 1, y = 1, d, wt;
    float balance;

    /* Welcome message */
    printf ("Thank you for using The Matrix banking system. Where you always take the red pill.\n\n");

    /* Prompt for name */
    printf ("Please enter your name: ");
    gets (name);
    printf ("\nHello %s.\n\n", name);

    /* Prompt for account balance, makes sure ammount is 0 or more */
    do
    {
        printf ("Now enter your current balance in dollars and cents: $");
        scanf ("%f", &balance);
        fflush(stdin);

        if ( balance < 0 )
            printf ("Error: Beginning balance must be at least zero, please re-enter!\n\n"); /* Error message for negative balance amount */

    } while ( balance <= 0 );/* end loop */

    /* Enter the number of withdrawals, and number of deposits. Must be 0 or more */

    do
    {
        printf ("\nEnter the number of withdrawals: ");
        scanf ("%i", &number_of_withdrawals);
        fflush(stdin);

        if ( number_of_withdrawals < 0 || number_of_withdrawals > 50 )
        printf ("Number of withdrawals must be at least zero, but no more than 50.\nPlease re-enter!\n\n"); /* Error message for negative number of withdrawals */

    } while ( number_of_withdrawals < 0 || number_of_withdrawals > 50 );/* end loop */

    do
    {
        printf ("\nEnter the number of deposits: ");
        scanf ("%i", &number_of_deposits);
        fflush(stdin);

        if ( number_of_deposits < 0 || number_of_deposits > 50 )
        printf ("Number of deposits must be at least zero, but no more than 50.\nPlease re-enter!\n\n"); /* Error message for negative number of deposits */

    } while ( number_of_deposits < 0 || number_of_deposits > 50 );/* end loop */

    printf ("\n\n\n"); /* for spacing */

    /* Assign value to deposits. Must be positive number. */

    do
    { 
        printf ("Enter the amount of deposit #%i: ", x);
        scanf ("%f", &deposit[d]);

        if ( deposit[d] <= 0 )
        printf ("Error: Deposit amount must be more than 0\n");
        if ( deposit[d] <= 0 )
        balance = balance - deposit[d];
        else
        x++;
        balance = balance + deposit[d];

    } while ( x <= number_of_deposits );

    printf ("\n\n");

    do
    { 
        if ( balance == 0 )
        {
            printf ("You are out of money in The Matrix, take the blue pill.");
            break;
        }

        else    
            printf ("Enter the amount of withdrawals #%i: ", y);
            scanf ("%f", &withdrawal[wt]);
            balance = balance - withdrawal[wt];

            if ( balance < 0 )
            {
                printf ("***Withdrawal amount exceeds current balance.***\n");
                y--;
                balance = balance + withdrawal[wt];
            }
            else if ( withdrawal[wt] <= 0 )
                {
                printf ("Error: Withdrawal amount must be more than 0\n");
                balance = balance + withdrawal[wt];
                }
                else
                y++;

    } while ( y <= number_of_withdrawals );


    getchar();/* to pause output*/

    return 0;
} /*End main */
```

Comment: I do hope that you are not writing the software for my bank :-) `d` is not initialized in `scanf ("%f", &deposit[d])`. `wt` is not initialized in `scanf ("%f", &withdrawal[wt])`. `gets()` is a completely unsafe function. `fflush(stdin)` is undefined behaviour (unless perhaps on Linux) ...

Comment: I realize now that I was just assigning new values to the same array subscript, because I added variables to the loop, as opposed to increasing the counter inside the array. Thanks for the answers though.

Answer (score 1):

You have not initialized the variable `wt` anywhere in the program. Hence the program crashes here

> scanf ("%f", &withdrawal[wt]);

Initialize the variable. Also you are not handling the incrementing part of `wt` anywhere in the code. You may need to alter that